# How we know the product status from in app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to get list of available items from in app. I got product details when i pass list of skus. But i can't recognize whether the product is active or not .What should i do to get the status also. I got the following sku response.

```
{"title":"test (pInAppTest)","price":"Rs.62.00","type":"inapp","description":"test description","price_amount_micros":62000000,"price_currency_code":"INR","productId":"65"}
```